# Maximize $\mathbb{E}_{x}\left\{\|H x\|_{2}^{2}\right\}$ subject to ${trace}\left\{Covariance_{x x}\right\}=\alpha>0 .$

Tags: matrices, optimization, expected-value, covariance, trace

Let  $\boldsymbol{H} \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix and x be a zero-mean signal vector
$x \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$ that has a covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{x x}$.

For a known H, I want to: **obtain $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{x x}$ to maximize $\mathbb{E}_{x}\left\{\|\boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{x}\|_{2}^{2}\right\}$ subject to
$\operatorname{trace}\left\{\Sigma_{xx}\right\}=\alpha>0$**
Here is my attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{E}\|H x\|_{2}^{2}\\
&\mathbb{E}\left(\operatorname{tr}\left({x}^{H} H^{H} \cdot {H} \cdot{x}\right)\right\}\\
&\mathbb{E}\left\{\operatorname{tr}\left\{H \cdot{x}\left(x^{H} H^{H}\right)\right]\right.\\
&\operatorname{tr}\left\{H \cdot\left\{\mathbb{E}(x x^{H})\right\} H^{H}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$tr \left\{H \cdot \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{x x}\cdot H^{H}\right\} $$
Now I am stuck at this point and a I don't know how to proceed or make use of $\operatorname{trace}\left\{\Sigma_{xx}\right\}=\alpha>0$.

Any suggestions ??